# Fixing nested Base.lproj/Base.lproj made new files unlocalizable

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, interface-builder

I have a strange nested Base.lproj situation, where my filesystem looks like this:

```
ProjectName
    Base.lproj
        Authentication.storyboard
        SidebarViewController.xib
        Base.lproj // <-- What?????
            LoginViewController.xib
        en-US.lproj // <-- What????
            LoginViewController.strings
            SidebarViewController.strings
    en-US.lproj
        Authentication.strings
```

When I copied `LoginViewController.xib` into the top-level Base.lproj and unchecked/rechecked the English checkbox on `SidebarViewController.xib`, I can delete the nested Base and en-US folders and build successfully.

> It's fixed! But wait...

I create a new file (e.g. `Dummy.storyboard`), it is added to the correct folder:

```
ProjectName
    Base.lproj
        Authentication.storyboard
        SidebarViewController.xib
        LoginViewController.xib
        Dummy.storyboard
    en-US.lproj
        Authentication.strings
        LoginViewController.strings
        SidebarViewController.strings
```

**BUT** when I check English in the Localization section, I get this error:

> The file path ~/project_ios.git/ProjectName/ProjectName/en.lproj/Dummy.storyboard is invalid. The expected prefix is ~/project_ios.git/ProjectName/ProjectName/Base.lproj

What am I missing? I cleaned the build, deleted Xcode's DerivedData directory, and intermediate build projects directory, and nothing is making a difference.

Comment: You might want to blow away your entire project and start over fresh. Are you using an updated version of XCode? What version of XCode are you using?